# Can We Get Vue to 'Detect Changes' to an Array If We Use `Filter()`?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

First, I had this: `parts = parts.filter(part => part.id !== change.doc.id);`

So, `data` is an `Array` and it gets 'clobbered' with a new 'filtered' `Array`.

Vue didn't seem keen on detecting the change and updating my DOM.

So, I saw [this.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) Specifically: *To deal with caveat 2, you can use splice:*

I refactored (or is it 'de-factored' b/c my code 'grew'?) to this:

```
// Get index of part removed
        const index = parts.forEach((part, i) => {
          if (part.id === change.doc.id) {
            return i;
          }
        });

    parts.splice(index, 1);
```

She works...but really? Do I *have* to do this way?

Comment: Use the `computed ()` method and return that as your filtered data

Comment: IDT `computed` will help. There is an `async` call that happens and updates occur. IT there is some plugin to do `async` and `computed`, but that's overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    parts.splice(parts.findIndex(part => part.id === change.doc.id), 1);
```

I got the `splice` in there while still keeping as 1 line, so m happy!